# I am having an issue with testing my android application, The application is running fine on my device but it crash on MI phones

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-testing

I also tried to run the test on the firebase test lab with Robo script, and it worked fine with mi phones. Now what is the standard way of testing application for all mobile phones brand and how can I deal with the issues that only happen in some specific android devices? Are these devices not following the standards (like Microsoft did with internet explorer).

I also tried to make virtual machine of Mi mobile in android studio as well as Genymotion but was unable to do that, kindly guide me and sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I don't have MI phone, :(

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :) your question is a bit hard for us to help you with, as we have even less info than you, the best suggestion would possibly be to try and implement something like crashlytics or any other crash reporting system to get more info on what is crashing

Comment: then when you have a stack trace and a general idea of what is crashing, you can ask a more detailed question here. be sure to include your code and your stack trace

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I already implemented crash analytics but the crash reports do not show up at the time, (as I have observed sometimes one day delay is there). I have to wait for a day to check the logs ?